# How to prevent Next.js from instantiating a singleton class/object multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have an analytics utility like this:

```
class Analytics {
    data: Record<string, IData>;

    constructor() {
        this.data = {};
    }
    setPaths(identifier: string) {
        if (!this.data[identifier])
            this.data[identifier] = {
                generic: getGenericInit(),
                session: getSessionInit(),
                paths: {
                    geoCollectionPath: '',
                    sessionCollectionPath: '',
                    eventsCollectionPath: ''
                }
            };
        this.data[identifier].paths = {
            geoCollectionPath: getGeoPath(identifier),
            sessionCollectionPath: getSessionPath(identifier),
            eventsCollectionPath: getEventPath(identifier)
        };
    }
    getAll() {
        return this.data;
    }
}

const analytics = new Analytics();
export default analytics;
```

And I import it into 2 api folders: `e1.ts` and `e2.ts`.

`e1.ts`:

```
import { NextApiHandler } from 'next';
import analytics from '@/firebase/v2/analytics';

const handler: NextApiHandler = (req, res) => {
    analytics.setPaths('abc');
    return res.status(201).end();
};
export default handler;
```

and `e2.ts`:

```
import { NextApiHandler } from 'next';
import analytics from '@/firebase/v2/analytics';

const handler: NextApiHandler = (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).json(analytics.getAll());
};
export default handler;
```

Now even when I add the data by hitting `/api/e1` since the import instantiates a fresh class in `e2`, I fail to retrieve the data from `/api/e2`. How can I achieve my use case for this?

I also tried using `static` instance but that doesn't work as well. Can someone help me in finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[In development, Next clears Node.js cache on run](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/nextjs-prisma-client-dev-practices), so every time there is a "compiling..." in the terminal (which happens per page render), it starts as a new app, losing any previous variable.

This is why, in this [article](https://vercel.com/guides/nextjs-prisma-postgres), down to the section where they instantiate a `PrismaClient`, to have it created only once, they use the `global` object, in your case, like so:

```typescript
let analytics;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  analytics = new Analytics();
} else {
  if (!global.analytics) {
    global.analytics = new Analytics();
  }
  analytics = global.analytics;
}

export default analytics;
```