# Manage value from a global variable NextJs

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have 2 routes (example1 and example2), I want to have a global general variable that can be accessible by these 2 routes.

One example:

```
//api/variable.ts
let test = 0
```

```
//api/example1.ts

setTest =() => {
  test=2
}
```

```
//api/example2.ts

getTest =() => {
  return test
}
```

Now I want to call some routes and the value of the variable should be updated

```
// mainFile.ts

setTest()
getTest() // It should return 2, but it returns 0
```

How could I create a global variable like that? I tried to use a singleton class just for this variable, but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Next.js from instantiating a singleton class/object multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75272877/how-to-prevent-next-js-from-instantiating-a-singleton-class-object-multiple-time)

Comment: @YoussoufOumar ohhhhhhh now it makes sense.... Thanks a lot, such a tricky behaviour.