# State of global variables in route.js not persisting between requests

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0

I have a route handler in my NextJS project that is supposed to store two tokens upon receiving a POST request from my authorization API. When the route receives a GET request it is supposed to yield one of the tokens stored previously. The following is the route.js representing the route handler:

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
const BASE_URI = process.env.BASE_URI;

// SEE: GLOBAL VARIABLES INITIALIZED AS NULL
let access_token = null;
let refresh_token = null;

// stores initial tokens
export async function POST(req) {
  const tokens = await req.json();

  // SEE: GLOBAL VARIABLES STORING TOKENS
  access_token = tokens.access_token;
  refresh_token = tokens.refresh_token;

  console.log(tokens);

  return NextResponse.redirect(BASE_URI + "home/");
}

// gets access_token
export async function GET(req) {
  
  // SEE: GLOBAL VARIABLE IS CHECKED TO ENSURE THAT THE POST REQUEST OCCURRED
  if(access_token === null) {
    console.log("Authorization Error");
    return new NextResponse("Authorization Error");
  } else {
    return new NextResponse.json({access_token: access_token});
  }
}
```

The problem is that once the GET request occurs after the POST request it recognizes the access_token as null, despite my saving it.

Thanks for reading and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Next.js from instantiating a singleton class/object multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75272877/how-to-prevent-next-js-from-instantiating-a-singleton-class-object-multiple-time)

Comment: @YoussoufOumar thanks for the recommendation. i have decided that i was going about it wrong based on how next js works and will now be using a session store.