# Next.js 13 - Redis Singleton in Route Handler

Tags: next.js, redis

I have a simple library file that wraps some redis functionality:

```js
import Redis from 'ioredis'

// TTL will be an hour
const TTL = 3600

console.log('In redis.ts, doing things')
const client = new Redis(process.env.REDIS_URL || '')

client.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('[REDIS] - Connection Established.')
})

const set = (k: string, v: string) => {
  return client.set(k, v, 'EX', TTL)
}

const get = (k: string) => {
  return client.get(k)
}

export { get, set }
```

Then, in a simple route handler, I do something like this:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import { set } from '@/lib/redis'

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  await set('myKey', JSON.stringify({ some: 'data' }))
  return NextResponse.json({ success: true })
}
```

Every time that handler is invoked, my redis `on` event fires and my logs spit out what I'm logging above:

```
In redis.ts, doing things
[REDIS] - Connection Established.
```

I'm using a free-tier of Upstash, which gives you 100 simultaneous connections, and I'm quickly hitting that limit when testing locally.

I tried exporting the redis client directly to no avail; this seems to refuse to want to use what I'd assume should be a singleton. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Next.js from instantiating a singleton class/object multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75272877/how-to-prevent-next-js-from-instantiating-a-singleton-class-object-multiple-time)

Comment: It doesn't, unfortunately; it seems like every call to `get` or `set` creates a new connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out out http based client: https://github.com/upstash/upstash-redis

It uses stateless http connections, which solves your problem and also allow you run it at the edge, TCP is not supported