# how can i continuous stay connected with mongodb database in nextjs application?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, next.js13, next.js14

for ex, in pure backend project or in server folder we'll put connectDb() which is function to connect database from our application,which we'll put in our app.js file so with in that single file our database will stay connected in each routes and each operations.
In nextjs for i've put that connectDb() inside API folder in each routes.js file then it'll reconnect database in each routes that's why application might get slower in performence.

here is my code for database connection, can anyone give me ans that where should i put this function once so that i don't have to put connectDb() inside each routes.

```
const MongoUri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/*"

const connectDb = async () => {
  return mongoose.connect(
    MongoUri,
  ).then(() => console.log("Database connected successfully...")).catch(err => console.log("Error while connecting to db", err));
}
```

Comment: Have come accorss https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75272877/how-to-prevent-next-js-from-instantiating-a-singleton-class-object-multiple-time.