# How to access a common object or variable in different files in ts (next.js)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I use Next.js. I have one file with code:

```
export let counter = 0;
```

In the first file of api route /api/test1 I add number to counter:

```
counter += 5;
```

In the seconds file of api /api/test2 I want to get updated a value of counter:

```
console.log('counter', counter); // 5
```

But I get 0;

How can I get the current counter value in seconds file?

p.s. I simplified the task, using the example of a counter.

Comment: Hi Uoloar ! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please.

Answer (score 1):

During development, and because of hot reload, Next.js clears the Node.js cache on every request, resetting any variable in memory.

So fare a solution is to use the `global` object, for example like so:

```
class Counter {
  private count: number;

  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
  }

  increment() {
    this.count++;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.count--;
  }

  getCount() {
    return this.count;
  }
}

let counter: Counter;

declare global {
  var counter: Counter;
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  counter = new Counter();
} else {
  if (!global.counter) {
    global.counter = new Counter();
  }
  counter = global.counter;
}

export { counter };
```

This is highlighted on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75273986/15288641).